# Anyone with experience of targeting Silverlight & WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Is it possible to develop against Silverlight and WPF using the same source code? Maybe using some #define blocks where it is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically it should be doable. It's not a big problem for the code. However, you'll have to be very careful with XAML and use only the intersecting subset of WPF and SL (1), as there's no `#if/#endif` for XAML.

(1) Contrary to the common belief, SL is not a proper subset of WPF. It has [some features that WPF does not have](http://blogs.msdn.com/johngossman/archive/2008/08/08/visualstatemanager-for-desktop-wpf.aspx), though these are being worked on.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, PRISM (the composite application block from patterns and practices) now supports Silverlight and there's a [C9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Continuum/Prismv2/) with a quick sample on using code in both WPF and Silverlight.

I think if you stick to MV-V-VM (or something along those lines) then a lot of your backend code will be reusable, but the XAML itself might need to be forked if you want a full on "rich" experience, unless you are willing to use the VSM beta for WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience on that but I have used a component that targets both WPF and Silverlight environment with the same code (there are only few differences).

The component is Chart from [Visifire](http://visifire.com/) and it's Open Source

Maybe you can take a look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio file linking to include classes from WPF projects in Silverlight - but only if they don't do any UI or XAML based stuff (as this is where you will usually find inconsistencies between the two)...

So keep it to business logic etc.

Answer (score 0):

Flashcards.Show application is a great example of this WPF/SL/WP7 code sharing and cross platform possibilities. 
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/03/flashcards-show-planning-a-cross-platform-solution.aspx

Concept of cross platform is pretty simple because everything works on .NET and a similar XAML binding system. My advice here is to invest more time on architecture of the app in terms of MVVM and other abstraction to segregate the platform dependencies. So that a major percentage of the code can be re-used across while some of the XAML might need to rewrite depends on the visual complexity of the app in different platforms.